# Running htxelatex in nonstopmode

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I am trying to run htxelatex in nonstomode

Here are my tries:

```
htxelatex manual.tex config.cfg "-interaction=nonstopmode"
htxelatex manual.tex config.cfg "--interaction=nonstopmode"
htxelatex manual.tex config.cfg "" "" "-interaction=nonstopmode"
htxelatex manual.tex config.cfg "" "" "" "-interaction=nonstopmode"
```

None of them seems to work, I am also trying `batchmode` but same result

Comment: I don't think you need the quotes. I'd also moving the interaction to the front:
`htxelatex -interaction=nonstopmode manual.tex config.cfg`